# Maven project Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer

Tags: java, spring, maven

Am running the class below in my Maven project

```
package com.zra.test;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import com.zra.proxy.NickGateway;

public class ProxyPublisher {
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        System.out.println("Publishing ProxyService at http://localhost:8280/ZRAProxy/ZRAProxy...");
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8280/ZRAProxy/ZRAProxy", new NickGateway());
        System.out.println("Proxy service successfully published on http://localhost:8280/ZRAProxy/ZRAProxy");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception publishing webservice");
      }
   }
}
```

I want to test my application but i get the below error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.<init>(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:170)
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<init>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:170)
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
  at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:148)
       at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:122)
       at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:94)
       at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:83)
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:106)
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.createThreadBus(BusFactory.java:243)
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:227)
       at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:214)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:131)
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:154)
       at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
       at com.zra.test.ProxyPublisher.main(ProxyPublisher.java:11)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
       ... 24 more
```

Here is my dependency, I have changed my dependency to 3.1.3.RELEASE i get an error in my pom.xml

```
      <repository>
    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
    <name>Spring Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>http://s3.amazonaws.com/maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
  <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
  <spring-batch.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring-batch.version> 
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This class is available since 4.0. Look at here

[Class DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.html)

You should upgrade **spring-core** artifact to 4.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You have some spring dependencies of version `3.1.3.RELEASE` and some of `4.0.2.RELEASE`. Try using dependencies of same version. I guess mixed versions of spring dependencies is causing the problems.

Read `Maven "Bill Of Materials" Dependency` section in [spring reference documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html).

Comment: I had tried to change the dependencies to 3.1.3.RELEASE but that generated an error in my pom.xml. can i change this       <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version> to <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>